# Monotouch key value coding-compliant crashes on running a storyboard project

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

After I add a simple button or component to the storyboard, then running on debug, I receive a message stating that there is a key value coding problem. If I clean the solution its builds OK, but if I add another component I get same error again.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the full exception info? Stack traces are always awesome.

Comment: Or link to a sample project?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4u9blwk83oi53v/StoryboardTables.zip here is the link of project

Answer (score 1):

## Edited after seeing the problem

The problem seems to be present on Xamarin Studio - here is [bug report #15002](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15002) on Xamarin's Bugzilla. I'll add a [github repository](https://github.com/arlm/StoryboardTables) with the sample to reproduce the problem. It occurs only on the device and not on the simulator.

---

## Old answer

Your problem occurs when attatching the running instance to an `AppDelegate`. Your `AppDelegate.cs` file may have a class that is not registered. Try verifying if your file content is similar to this:

Specially this part:

```
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
```

---

Full file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace StoryBoardTables
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;
        PaintCodeViewController viewController;
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            viewController = new PaintCodeViewController ();
            window.RootViewController = viewController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think its from appdelegate, because its runs on simulator but in device its not, in everytime i need to clean rebuild and build.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4u9blwk83oi53v/StoryboardTables.zip here is the link

Comment: I ran it on my simulator without problems. Can you send some steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Dear Alexendre, its allright with sim, but.. on device. if i add any component crashes ( wich one at first post picture key value coding compliant ) :(

in other way i can fix like every before build ( clean all, clean project , delete bin, delete obj, rebuild and run..) blah thats kills me

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run on my device for 10 days. It is "on a mission" on another city. ;-) Is there any other way to reproduce this problem? Can you post the complete stack trace (on the outuput window of Xamarin Studio).

Comment: Dear Alexendre, when you got time,  you can directly connect my pc with teamviewer maybe? You i'll be really a great hero for me if we can handle this :) Because if i can't i need to backup twice a day and if i get this stuck i need to recover ever ever and ever.. haluky@live.com is contact mail of mine